# Invalid table name error on PHP/SQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

My registration page on my website is displaying the error message: invalid table name when registering a new account into it's database.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/localhost.php'); ?>
 <?php
  if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
   function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
  {
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
   }

 $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?  mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

 switch ($theType) {
 case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
 }
 return $theValue;
 }
  }

 // *** Redirect if username exists
 $MM_flag="MM_insert";
 if (isset($_POST[$MM_flag])) {
 $MM_dupKeyRedirect="Register.php";
 $loginUsername = $_POST['UserName2'];
 $LoginRS__query = sprintf("SELECT Username FROM `user` WHERE Username=%s", GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"));
 mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
 $LoginRS=mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
 $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);

 //if there is a row in the database, the username was found - can not add the   requested username
if($loginFoundUser){
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  //append the username to the redirect page
  if (substr_count($MM_dupKeyRedirect,"?") >=1) $MM_qsChar = "&";
   $MM_dupKeyRedirect = $MM_dupKeyRedirect . $MM_qsChar ."requsername=".$loginUsername;
  header ("Location: $MM_dupKeyRedirect");
  exit;
  }
   }

   $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
   if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
   $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    }

    if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "RegisterForm")) {
 $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO ``user`` (Fname, Lname, Email, Username,   Password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['FName'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['LName'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Email'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['UserName2'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Password'], "text"));

 mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());

$insertGoTo = "Login.php";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 }
 header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
  }

   mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
   $query_Register = "SELECT * FROM `user`";
   $Register = mysql_query($query_Register, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_Register = mysql_fetch_assoc($Register);
    $totalRows_Register = mysql_num_rows($Register);
     ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.js"    type="text/javascript"></script><script   src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationConfirm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationPassword.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationConfirm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationPassword.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   </head>
    <link href="CSS/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="CSS/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <body>
    <div id="Holder"></div>
     <div id="Header"></div>
     <div id="NavBar">
      <nav> 
     <ul> 

      <li><a href="Login.php">Login</a></li>
       <li><a href="Register.php">Register</a></li>
       <li><a href="ForgotPassword.php">Forgot Password</a></li>
      </ul>


       </nav>

       </div>
      <div id="Content"></div>
      <div id="ContentLeft">
      <h1>Sign Up!</h1>
       </div>
       <div id="ContentRight">
       <form id="RegisterForm" name="RegisterForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
       <table width="400" border="1" align="center">
       <tr>
         <td><table border="1">
          <tr>
           <td><h6><span id="sprytextfield1">
           <label for="FName"></label>
           <input type="text" name="FName" id="FName" />
          <br />
          First Name: </span></h6>
          <span><span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
        <td><h6><span id="sprytextfield2">
          <label for="LName"></label>
          <input type="text" name="LName" id="LName" />
          <br />
          Last Name: </span></h6>
          <span><span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.   </span></span></td>
         </tr>
        </table></td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
           <td><h6 class="StyleTxtField">Email:
          <input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" />
          </h6></td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
          <td><span id="sprytextfield3">
         <label for="Email"></label>
         <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><h6 class="StyleTxtField">UserName:          
           <input name="UserName2" type="text" id="UserName2" />
            </h6></td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
    <td><span id="sprytextfield4">
      <label for="UserName"></label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>   </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><table border="1">
               <tr>
           <td><h6 class="StyleTxtField">Password:<span id="sprypassword1">
             <label for="Password"></label>
             <input name="Password" type="password" class="StyleTxtField" id="Password" />
               <span class="passwordRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></h6></td>
        <td><h6><span class="StyleTxtField" id="spryconfirm1">
          <label for="PasswordConfirm"></label>
          <br />
          Confirm Password:<br />
          <input name="PasswordConfirm" type="password" class="StyleTxtField" id="PasswordConfirm" />
          <br />
          <br />
                        : </span></h6>
          <span><span class="confirmRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="confirmInvalidMsg">The values don't match.</span></span></td>
      </tr>
         </table></td>
           </tr>
             <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="RegisterButton" id="RegisterButton" value="Register" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="25"><table border="1">
      <tr> </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> </tr>
  <tr> </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="24"><table border="1">
      <tr> </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
      </table>
   <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="RegisterForm" />
        </form>
           </div>


          <div id="Footer"></div>
           </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              var sprytextfield4 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield4");
             var sprytextfield3 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield3", "email");
             var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield1");
             var sprytextfield2 = new                Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield2");
            var spryconfirm1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationConfirm("spryconfirm1", "Password");
              var sprypassword1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationPassword("sprypassword1");
                   </script>
               </body>
            </html>
             <?php
           mysql_free_result($Register);
            ?>
```

Thank you for attempting to debug my code you are all greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's one step to debugging the code:  output the value of the `$insertSQL` string, before it's submitted to the database as a SQL statement. (If you don't have a logging facility, just use `echo` or `vardump`.)  Once you figure out the problem with the SQL statement, you can fix the code. (btw... StackOverflow is *not* a debugging service. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ )

Comment: thank you for that, I'll be sure to use it in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is

```
``user``
```

should be

```
`user`
```

---

BUT: you have a bigger problem. Don't use mysql_ functions as they are no longer included in PHP. Your code will not work in a year or so's time.

Check out [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Thank you!! I would've never found that... Also, thank you for the tip!